# Combining means of means where the means are averages (%).

Tags: probability

I have a series of means (percentage returns) on differing amounts of principle. Since the sample size in each series is the same should the differing principle be used, i.e, should the means be weighted??
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously.

$$\frac{\dfrac{0+0}2+\dfrac{1+1+1}3}{2}\ne\frac{0+0+1+1+1}5,$$

while

$$\frac{2\cdot\dfrac{0+0}2+3\cdot\dfrac{1+1+1}3}{2+3}=\frac{0+0+1+1+1}5.$$

Comment: They look the same to me- let me be more specific. I'm trying to compute the Combined Standard Deviation of 3 groups of returns- its in this capacity that I need the mean of the means, so, suppose on one investment of $1000 I'm getting an average return of 3% and on an investment of $7000 I'm getting a 4% average return- show the calc of the mean of the 3% & the 4%??

Comment: THe example shown looks the same to me- Anyway, let me be more specific If I have a $100 investment earning an average of 3% and $7000 earning and average of 4%, show the calculation for the combined mean?

Comment: @Johndepierro: I have modified to better show the difference.